# SCSM 2012 Retrieving Incident Logs SDK

Tags: c#, servicemanager

I'm attempting to write some C# to retrieve Incident Logs using the SCSM 2012 SDK. I have successfully been able to retrieve Incidents, Analyst Comments, and Action Logs, but am having issues finding incident logs.

The only way I have found to retrieve them is to pass each Incident one at a time and this way does not seem to be very efficient.

Besides using straight SQL Queries to the Service Manager Database, does anyone know of a way of retrieving bulk Incident Logs from Service Manager through Code?